# Как сгруппировать `div` по 4 штуки?

Tags: javascript, массивы, dom

Изначально есть такая структура:

```
<body>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
    <div class="box">7</div>
    <div class="box">8</div>
    <div class="box">9</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
    <div class="box">11</div>
    <div class="box">12</div>
</body>
```

В результате должна получиться такая:

```
<div class="row1">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
</div>
<div class="row2">
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
    <div class="box">7</div>
    <div class="box">8</div>
</div>
<div class="row3">
    <div class="box">9</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
    <div class="box">11</div>
    <div class="box">12</div>
</div>
```

То есть необходимо добиться того, чтобы элементы группировались по 4 штуки в отдельный `div` с классом `row-n`, где `n` - это номер "группы" элементов.

Пытался реализовать так:

```
'use strict'
var arr = [];
var row1 = [];
var row2 = [];
var row3 = [];
arr.push(document.getElementsByClassName('box'));
var boxes = arr[0];
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    if(i < 4) {

            row1.push(boxes[i])
    } else if(i >= 4 && i < 8) {

            row2.push(boxes[i])
    } else {

            row3.push(boxes[i])
    }
};
```

Но ничего не вышло.

Comment: В смысле каждый div с классом `box` обернуть в отдельный div с классом `raw-n`? Или наоборот в каждый div с классом `box` засунуть 3 div'а с классами `raw-1` (2, 3)?

Comment: нужен такой результат
   https://codepen.io/agafron/pen/zEgwKB

Comment: Добавьте это в вопрос (кнопка править), потому что в таком виде читать невозможно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var box, raw, i = 1, z = 1;

// ключевой момент здесь. Пока внутри родителя есть элементы с классом .box (родитель
// в данном случае - body, но у вас может быть любой), то выполняем тело цикла.
while (box = document.querySelector("body > .box")) {
    // i - номер итерации. Инкрементируется в конце цикла. Если переваливает за 4, то начинаем
    // отсчет заново (это нужно, чтобы сгруппировать элементы по 4 штуки)
    if (i > 4) {
        i = 1;
    }

    // если это первый заход в группе, то создаем новый div с классом raw-z
    if (i === 1) {
        // переопределяем raw в новый, свжесозданный div
        raw = document.createElement("div");
        // с классом raw-z
        raw.classList.add("raw-" + z);
        // после чего z увеличиваем
        z += 1;
    }

    // в созданный на "первом" проходе div с классом raw-z добавляем box'ы
    raw.appendChild(box);

    // если это последний элемент из группы, то отрисовываем всю группу элементов
    if (i === 4) {
        document.body.appendChild(raw);
    }

    // увеличиваем счетчик на 1
    i += 1;
}
```

Comment: Круть! Спасибо, то что надо!

Comment: Еще поправочка. В последней внутри цикла проверке я отрисовываю все в `document.body`, но вы, конечно же, можете отрисовывать где угодно. Только не забудьте поправить селектор в условии цикла.

Comment: еще вопрос, это можно через for реализовать?

Comment: @agafron разумеется. `for (box = document.querySelector("body > .box"); box;) {}`.

Comment: Не проверял, но, по идее, должно работать. Но вообще это здесь ни к чему, `while` тут более уместен. Можно, конечно, вообще всю логику переделать, чтобы было элегантно и с `for`, но это уже совсем другая история. И, вероятнее всего, с массивами и вложенными циклами.

Comment: Спасибо большое! буду постигать дальше)